# Why I can't set a query builder first result to a Livewire component? PublicPropertyTypeNotAllowedException

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

My problem is that: **Livewire\Exceptions\PublicPropertyTypeNotAllowedException**

*Obs.: I can't use Eloquent, because this project is connected to a lot of different databases and I can't map all the tables (more than 500~1000 tables).*

**The error:**

> Livewire\Exceptions\PublicPropertyTypeNotAllowedException
> Livewire component's [alteracao-gestor-terceiro] public property [terceiro] must be of type: [numeric, string, array, null, or boolean]. Only protected or private properties can be set as other types because JavaScript doesn't need to access them.

**livewire component**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Gestor;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Livewire\Component;

class AlteracaoGestorTerceiro extends Component
{
    public $terceiro, $codTerceiro, $codNovoGestor;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.alteracao-gestor-terceiro');
    }

    public function busca()
    {
         $this->terceiro = DB::connection('xpto')
             ->table('cad_terceiros')
             ->where('cod_terceiro', $this->codTerceiro)
             ->first();
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```php
    <x-list.dl.item column='cod_terceiro' :value="$terceiro->cod_terceiro" />
```

Comment: Have you tried using `toArray()`? `$this->terceiro = .....->first()->toArray();`

Comment: Yes: Error - Call to undefined method stdClass::toArray()

Comment: What about replacing `first()` with `limit(1)->get()->toArray()`?

Comment: FYI: You *can* use Eloquent; you can specify for each model which connection they should use.

Comment: What does the rest of your component look like?

Comment: I can't use Eloquent, because I dont any the models mapped. All queries are using DB Query Builder, because I'm using a lot of different databases.

Comment: We don't know what `terceiro->cod_terceiro` is. Can't you convert it to a numeric, string, array, null, or boolean?

Comment: $terceiro is a Query Builder object. cod_terceiro is a string, it's a parameter from the "terceiros" table. In english is => $partners->username